# Colorbox redirect to url in parent window after login

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using colorbox for the login window and upon success, I want to redirect the user to index.php in the parent frame. I'm missing some detail and it's redirecting index.php in the colorbox itself. Where do I declare the 'parent' parameter for the target?

I'm posting the parts of my code which enable the colorbox etc:

Link that opens colorbox:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a.logmein").colorbox({rel: 'logmein', iframe:true, width:"540", height:"400", onClosed:function(){ location.reload(true); }});
});
```

Check user's credentials:

```
if($totalRows_finduser==0){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(document).ready(function() {
            $.colorbox({href:\'login.php\', iframe:true, transition:"fade", width:"540", height:"400"});
    });
  </script>';

} else {    
    $_SESSION['login'] = 1; 
        // I set the user as logged in, assign the session vars etc
        // HOW DO I REDERECT HIM FROM HERE TO PARENT??

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a different way to think about this.  Why assign the routing (redirect) job to the login popup.

Consider making the job of the popup to (i) get login credentials and (ii) authenticate them. If the credentials fail, stay in the popup. If they pass, close the popup passing the result of the action back to the parent. Let the parent perform routing for there.

You should also consider the case of an end user simply closing the login popup; either prevent that from happening, or add a signal to the parent that covers that case.

If you prefer to route from within the popup, remember that the parent's Window object is accessible to you. So load **window.parent.location** with some URI.

kjm

Comment: Thanks! Worked well. window.parent.location. Added bounty ;)